# How to implement multiple class selectors like .a.b in Emotion?

Tags: reactjs, emotion, css-in-js, emotion-js

I'm migrating some CSS to Emotion, some selectors are like .a.b {...}. What's the best way to use Emotion for this?

I've tried css`.${a}.${b}` but it doesn't work :(